# visual studio 2010 confirmation on close

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want VS2010 to ask me when I am closing the whole environment whether I am sure about closing VS2010 or not.

Unfortunately I couldn't find this setting anywhere

Anybody knows?

Comment: No such feature in VS, a good thing imo. Of course it asks if you want to close open files, also a good thing. I get annoyed when an app demands to know if I really, ***really*** mean it when (in VS, say) I've already clicked on two things to close a solution.

Comment: thanks. sometimes accidentally I close it, so looked for such a setting

Comment: Yeah, me too. But it's so easy to reopen, with an MRU list, yet, that I don't miss it.

Comment: I have the same issue, I sometimes accidentally hit alt+f4 when I were going to close some merge diff editors, my VS solution takes like ages to reopen... so no such a prompt is very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no such option. However, there is an old tool called [NoClose](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#NoClose) that can disable the (X) button for you (see [LifeHacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5183947/noclose-disables-windows-close-button) about this tool)

Though I haven't used it under Windows 7/8, I'm not sure if it is compatible.

Comment: NoClose is at http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/NoClose/NoClose.ahk and it works for me (Vs2013, Win7) in that it suppresses the Windows native close item on the system menu.  this works for me because I use the keyboard not the mouse.  Unfortunately VS 2013 uses owner drawn window decorations so the X in the top right of the window remains so people who use the mouse to close still have the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this in Visual Studio 2010, but you can achieve this in Visual Studio 2008 at least by using an Automation Macro.  The instructions below work for 2008, and shouldn't be too hard to translate to 2010 (hopefully).

Open up the Macro IDE (Tools->Macros->MacroIDE), and in the list of Macros you should see an item `EnvironmentEvents`.  Double-click this to get a module containing the existing Environment Event macros.

In the drop-down list select `SolutionEvents`, and then in the Declarations list select `QueryCloseSolution`.  What we're doing is creating a macro that is run whenever you try to close a Solution.  We'll create a messagebox to ask the user if they really want to do it, and optionally cancel the shutdown - you should end up with something like this:

```
Private Sub SolutionEvents_QueryCloseSolution(ByRef fCancel As Boolean) Handles SolutionEvents.QueryCloseSolution
    If (MsgBox("Close the solution?", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel) = MsgBoxResult.Cancel) Then fCancel = True
End Sub
```

Save the Macro project, and try closing the solution, or shutting down Visual Studio.  If the stars are aligned you'll see a confirmation message box.  If you click "Cancel", the solution won't close, and VS won't shut down.

Now, perhaps someone can confirm in the comments if this works for VS2010?

Comment: Great solution @icabod - Confirmed on VS 2010.

Comment: There's no MacroIDE in VS2022.