# Handle FormClosing event (confirm close) of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vsix

I need to write an app to confirm closing of Visual Studio? I think, FormClosing event as in WinForms can be used and closing can be cancelled.

The main need is to prevent accidental exits of Visual Studio 2017. But VS 2015+ has Metro UI. [NoClose](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#NoClose) removes close menu from title bar right click menu, but cannot disable the right top close button.

**EDIT**

**Why is this needed:** Usually I have many open windows. I use WhatsApp desktop and this app is not starting in full screen. But it looks like it is maximized. And when I try to fast close it by moving pointer right top of the screen (on my right monitor, without even checking if the window is maximized), I actually click the app under that window. Which is mostly Visual Studio. And eventually VS closes. I'm working with a very large solution, so it takes very long time to open or close the solution. And since VS is not open source, I need somehow to confirm the exit. This is annoying and it happens too often (2-3 times in a day).

Also note I'm not the only developer who needs this and other IDEs already has such an option.

- https://superuser.com/q/155622
- [visual studio 2010 confirmation on close](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8942357/259881)
- https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/7576299-add-confirm-exit-option-to-preferences

Comment: How are you going to disable Task Manager's *End task* functionality? Or command line tools that can kill arbitrary processes.

Comment: How is the user supposed to close the app?

Comment: With confirmation. Ie. you can check Firefox prevent close plugin

Comment: I don't understand why anybody would want such a thing. I suspect that his is the wrong solution to the problem, whatever it is

Comment: @DavidHeffernan added more info.

Comment: Simple. Maximise WhatsApp using the keyboard. Alt+Space to open the system menu, X to invoke the maximize action.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This isn't resolving the main problem. Also you suggest to add 2-3 more actions to the task (UX wise). 1. Focus the window, 2. Press Alt+Space, 3. Press C. I may be closing all open windows over VS. Added info links.

Comment: I thought you wanted to maximise WhatsApp. To my mind that's your real problem. If you did that then your problem disappears.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do maximize those apps but sometimes I forget. It isn't only WhatsApp. Spotify, Slack etc. are also having/had same issues. I guess all apps build with something like https://electron.atom.io/ are having same problem.

Comment: In the Visual Studio case, you could write a VSIX extension that handles the  OnQueryCloseSolution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionevents3.onqueryclosesolution?view=visualstudiosdk-2017 , displays a messagebox 
, and acts accordingly, returning false or true (cancel or not)

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes that can solve my case. I was able to test this with a sample vsix (https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Build_Progress_Bar). But I need to write it from scratch. And make it work even when the tool is not visible.

Comment: @HasanGürsoy - VS extensions don't need windows, and can be configured to be loaded at startup with the ProvideAutoLoad attribute: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166762.aspx .  To write a package from scratch just select New Project/Extensibility/VSIX Project, and off you go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Created a simple (one-line) extension. 
Should do just that: prompt on closing Visual Studio :)

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NikolayBelyh.ClosePrompt2017

Just uses "QueryClose" for the package to rise the prompt:

https://github.com/nbelyh/ClosePrompt/blob/e583b2edc1a5a00104e69666b8fdc3efe6dd5896/ClosePrompt/ClosePromptPackage.cs#L56

Gimme 5 stars if it works ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the mighty Raymond Chen:

> Usability research indicates that users really don't like it when you disable the Close button. It makes them feel trapped and uncomfortable. This is the reason why standard Windows wizards don't provide a way for you to disable the Close button. The user should always have a way out.

I assume this is the kind of question where you don't care and just want a solution and he [also demonstrates a way](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100604-00/?p=13803) to disable the close button/menu:

```
void DisableCloseButton(HWND hwnd)
{
 EnableMenuItem(GetSystemMenu(hwnd, FALSE), SC_CLOSE,
                MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED);
}

void EnableCloseButton(HWND hwnd)
{
 EnableMenuItem(GetSystemMenu(hwnd, FALSE), SC_CLOSE,
                MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_ENABLED);
}
```

Depending on the application, this might not be enough and in those cases you need to [inject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces) code into the application and subclass the window so you can handle `WM_CLOSE`.

Comment: I'm the user and I don't want to disable close. I just want to confirm close and prevent accidental exit of an app. The final sentence is what I need :). Will google for it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8698923/259881